# How should i use the getter method in this situation?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, comparison, getter

I have a program (that acts as a game) containing two classes. The first class generates an array of characters and the second has the user try to guess whats in that array with their own array of characters. When the two classes connect, there has to be a getter method in the first class in order to compare the values from the computer generated array with the player made array in the second class.   This is the empty getter method:

```
- (char) getElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)i
{
}
```

I need the getter method to return the letter at I's position so that in another class it can be used to compare with in an if statement such as

```
if([_playerguess objectAtIndex:i]==[self.colorarray getElementAtIndex: i] )
```

how do i do this? i know i have to return something but the code i have tried has failed me so far.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? Also, what's `self.colorarray`?

Comment: Start by figuring out the data types you're going to use.  Since a `char` isn't an object, the idea of testing whether it's equal to any object from the `playerguess` array is a bad beginning.

Comment: self.colorarray is the reference to the array of characters created from the colorarray class, it is the one that is generated by the computer. In the main it goes like this 
    [colorarray fillArray];
    [player1 setColorarray:colorarray];
    [player1 initializeplayer];
The color array is computer generated and filled. The same array is then placed into player 1 class, and then the player is initialized so they can guess what is in this array.

Comment: That's an excellent point @PhillipMills. Chris, what I meant to ask is color array an nsarray? are you making a subclass of it? Some other object that contains another array?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what im doing. There is another class that is making the computer generated array: colorarray

Comment: So, There's one more things here to determine. Does colorarray contain an NSArray or a char[] as a representation for the computer generated data?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info to fully understand the question, but if I assume that colorarray has a property

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) char[] compData;
- (char) getElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)i;
```

Then I would think that

```
- (char) getElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)i{
    return self.compData[i];
}
```

would do the trick.